# Python in Binary Search Tree: The question of assignment operator in BST insert

Tags: python, pointers, tree

I have a Python BST class with an insert method. As far as I know the assignment `current_node = self.root` creates a reference `current_node` that points to the same address as `self.root`.

I'm confused about when I execute the line `current_node.left = Node(data)`, a new Node object gets assigned to both `current_node` and the `self.root` tree (given they reference the same object initially). Meanwhile, the assignment `current_node = current_node.left` only changes the pointer point to `current_node` and not `self.root`. Why?

Here's the code for reference:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, data):
    
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = Node(data)
        
        else:
            current_node = self.root
            while True:
                if current_node.data == data:
                    raise ExistError
                
                elif data < current_node.data:
                    if current_node.left:
                        current_node = current_node.left
                    else:
                        current_node.left = Node(data)
                        break
                
                else:
                    if current_node.right:
                        current_node = current_node.right
                    else:
                        current_node.right = Node(data)
                        break
```

Comment: `current_node = current_node.left` only changes what `current_node` points to. Why would `self.root` be changed? If you have 2 independent cameras pointing at you and one moves to point at someone else, would you expect the other camera to be now pointing at that someone else or still be pointing at you?

Comment: Maybe it's clearer when we think about lists rather than custom classes. Example 1: `x=[1,2]; y=x; x[0]=5; print(y)` Example 2: `x=[1,2]; y=x; x=[5,2]; print(y)`. Is it clear why those two examples behave differently?

Comment: `current_node.left = ...` MODIFIES (by granting it a left child) the object `current_node` points to (which is initially self.root). `current_node = ...`, however, REASSIGNS `current_node` to point to another object (which has no effect on the object current_node used to point to).